# Oracle SQL: For each class, list how many students are in each major

Tags: sql, database, oracle, relational-database

I'm in a database management class, and while I've been blazing through this week's homework, I've been stuck on this last question for a couple days: "For each class, list how many students are in each major. List class name, major, and count of students." The schema is as follows:

```
Student(*snum:* integer, *sname:* string, *major:* string, *level:* string, *age:* integer)
Class(*name:* string, *meets_at:* time, *room:* string, *fid:* integer)
Enrolled(*snum:* integer, *cname:* string)
Faculty(*fid:* integer, *fname:* string, *deptid:* integer)
```

I've figured out how to run this query for an individual class:

```
SELECT s.major, COUNT(s.snum)
FROM class c, student s, enrolled e
WHERE c.name=e.name AND s.snum=e.snum AND c.name='Class Name'
GROUP BY s.major;
```

I tried to do the following query, but the inner query doesn't have any context for c1, so I don't know where to go from here:

```
SELECT c1.name, s.major, totalstudents
FROM class c1, (SELECT s.major, COUNT(s.snum) AS totalstudents
                FROM class c, student s, enrolled e
                WHERE c.name=e.name AND s.snum=e.snum AND c.name=c1.name
                GROUP BY s.major)
GROUP BY c1.name;
```

So how do I do this?

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Start now, while you are learning SQL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `Class` name in `Select` and `Group by`

```
SELECT c1.NAME,
       s.major,
       Count(s.snum)
FROM   class c
       INNER JOIN enrolled e
               ON c.NAME = e.NAME
       INNER JOIN student s
               ON s.snum = e.snum
GROUP  BY s.major,
          c1.NAME
```

As mentioned in comments by Gordan, start using `INNER JOIN` syntax it more readable than Old style comma separated Join

Comment: That was it! I didn't even think of grouping by multiple columns. Also yeah, I'll totally use proper joins from now on. Either we haven't gone over them in class yet, or they weren't explained very well.